# Set Excel Autofilter Values with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, autofilter

My spreadsheet has an autofilter set to cell A8 that has the options L, B, U and (Blanks) and range A9:A532.

I would like a macro that when it has been run, its selects the B, U and (Blanks) options (or conversely deselects the L option) and therefore the relevant rows are filtered. I've had a look around what everything I have found so far hasn't worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use macrorecorder? Very often recorded macro gives the perfect how-to example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the recorded macro suggestion, for anyone else trying to achieve the same you get the following by using the macro recorder:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$A$532").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("B", _
        "U", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```